# Can not create contact in xero-node

Tags: node.js, xero-api

I use xero-node. I am trying to create contact this way:

> ```
> const create_contact: Contact = {
>             accountNumber: '******',
>             name: '*******',
>             brandingTheme: {
>                 brandingThemeID: '********-****-****-****-************',
>             },
>            salesDefaultLineAmountType: SalesDefaultLineAmountTypeEnum.EXCLUSIVE
> };
>
> const create_contacts: Contacts = {
>      contacts: [create_contact]
> };
> ```

...

> ```
> await xero.accountingApi.createContacts('myTenantId', create_contacts);
> ```

In the result I have Contact with name and account number.
Why I can't add brandingTheme and salesDefaultLineAmountType?

Comment: Can you add those elements once the contact has been created?

Comment: No, I tried add this elements after creating contact. As I found out, at the moment these fields cannot be set via API calls. It is possible to do it only via xero site

Comment: Ah, OK. Maybe you should add an answer to your question with that information, so it can be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, at the moment these fields cannot be set via API calls. It is possible to do it only via xero site